# Need to show appropriate message if no matching filterable records found

Tags: c#, kendo-grid

I have the following 2 simple requirements while dealing with Kendo Grid.

1. If there is no records present for the underlying datasource then display in the UI:
   `No records found. Please add New record using Add New button.`
2. If records present but on user click on any column Filter, and No matching records found then display in the UI:
   `No matching records found for the given search criteria.`

I have accomplished the 1st task using Grid's `OnDataBound()` method. I am just verifying the datasource length and displaying appropriate message in UI.

Please help me achieving the 2nd option. Because both of the case Grid's `datasource length is 0 (zero)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the clue:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    var filter = dataSource.filter();
    var message;
    if (this.dataSource._total === 0) {
        if (filter && filter.filters.length) {
            message = "No matching records found for the given search criteria.";
        } else {
            message = "No records found. Please add New record using Add New button.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query on the grid's dataSource's filter property. It will be `undefined` when filter is not defined or `null` when filters have been added but all have been removed.

So, basically your second option would be something like this or on the lines of this :

```
var grid = $("grid").data("kendoGrid");
if ((grid.dataSource.filter() != null) && (dataSource length is 0))
{
    //Display No matching records found....
}
```

Comment: The idea is good but what if underlying data is Empty and User tries to apply Filter on it? This time above condition will hold True and display the message "No matching records found!!!"